# [] and * operator overloading for a Rational class in c++

Tags: overloading, operator-keyword

I'm having difficulty trying to overload the `[]` and `*` operators. This is the given code:

```
#include<iostream>

class Rational {
  public:
    Rational (int numerator=0, int denominator = 1) : n(numerator), d(denominator) { }
  private:
    int n, d;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std :: ostream& out, const Rational& r) {
  return out << r[0] << '/' << r[1] << std::endl;
}

int main() {
  Rational rat1(2,3), rat2(3,4);

  std::cout << rat1 << std::endl;
  std::cout << rat1 * rat2 << std::endl;
}
```

Please overload [] and * operator for class Rational

```
I tried the following:
#include<iostream>
class Rational {
 public:
 Rational (int numerator=0 , int denominator = 1) :
 n(numerator),d(denominator)
 { }
 int operator[](int i){
  if(i==0)
   return n;
   else return d;
  }
 Rational& operator*(Rational& rhs){
  return *this(n*(rhs.n),d*(rhs.d));
 }
 private:
 int n,d;
};
std::ostream& operator<<(std :: ostream& out , const Rational& r) {
 return out<<r[0]<<'/'<<r[1]<<std::endl;
}
int main(){
 Rational rat1(2,3) , rat2(3,4);
 std::cout<<rat1<<std::endl;
 std::cout<<rat1*rat2<<std::endl;
}
```

After trying this I get the following errors:

```
error: passing ‘const Rational’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘int Rational::operator[](int)’ discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
 return out<<r[0]<<'/'<<r[1]<<std::endl;

error: passing ‘const Rational’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘int Rational::operator[](int)’ discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
 return out<<r[0]<<'/'<<r[1]<<std::endl;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I suspect the downvotes and votes to close are in response to the poor formatting of the code. You'll tend to get better replies if you put a little bit of effort into making your question easier to understand. So I fixed it for you.

Comment: It's also a good idea to show us what you've already tried. Otherwise it feels like you're just asking us to do your homework for you.

Comment: Thanks.I edited the code and I have also showed what I have tried but am unable to solve this thing.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line:

```
return *this(n * (rhs.n), d * (rhs.d));
```

It should be

```
return * new Rational(n * rhs.n, d * rhs.d);
```

You need to create and return a new `Rational` by calling the constructor, which is never done via the `this` pointer.

You should also validate the input: `rat1[6]` should generate an error.

Comment: I even tried doing that but in vain.The same error as before persists.